# Windsor set instance of a local variable?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I read the following code for Windsor installer.

```
public class MessagingInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        var subject = new Subject<IMessage>();
        var ss = Subject.Synchronize(subject);
        container.Rgister(
            Component.For<IObserver<IMessage>>().Instance(ss.AsObserver()),
            Component.For<IObservable<IMessage>>().Instance(ss.AsObservable()),
```

And classes inject `IObserver<IMessage> publisher`, which will call `publisher.OnNext(...)` to push values, and other classes inject `<IObservable<IMessage> source`, which subscribe `source`.

The question is `ss` is a local variable in the method `Install(...)`. How does `ss` be used by other classes?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use it from other classes. It's only in scope for the lifetime of the `Install()` method.

The instance returned from the `ss.AsObservable()` method call is being registered with the container, and *is* accessible to other classes via DI. I'm assuming that the instance returned by the `AsObservable()` method is not the same instance as `ss`?

If you want the instance `ss` refers to, to be accessible to other classes via DI, you would have to register that instance instead:

```
container.Register(Component.For<SomeType>().Instance(ss));
```